# extjs: Grid Buffered Scrolling with Row Editing/Deletion/Addition

Tags: extjs, grid

Has anybody seen any sample of extjs grid with buffered scrolling with new row, row editing and row deletion support?

Can CellEditing and RowEditing plugins be used with Buffered Scrolling?

Is row editing even possible with buffered scrolling?

Cheers,

Avi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had opened a thread at Ext forum and got the response, insertion and deletion is **NOT** supported with buffered scrolling.

http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?27969-Buffered-Scrolling-with-Row-Editing-Deletion-Addition&p=124559&posted=1#post124559

Cheers,

Avi

Answer (score 2):

I changed this example http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/grid/infinite-scroll.html, added the row editor. Open this example: http://jsfiddle.net/zAnZg/1/, click on record, change values and then click "Update"
[image]

```
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.util.*',
    'Ext.grid.plugin.BufferedRenderer'
]);


Ext.onReady(function(){
    Ext.define('ForumThread', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            'title', 'forumtitle', 'forumid', 'username', {
                name: 'replycount',
                type: 'int'
            }, {
                name: 'lastpost',
                mapping: 'lastpost',
                type: 'date',
                dateFormat: 'timestamp'
            },
            'lastposter', 'excerpt', 'threadid'
        ],
        idProperty: 'threadid'
    });

    // create the Data Store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        id: 'store',
        model: 'ForumThread',
        remoteGroup: true,
        // allow the grid to interact with the paging scroller by buffering
        buffered: true,
        leadingBufferZone: 300,
        pageSize: 100,
        proxy: {
            // load using script tags for cross domain, if the data in on the same domain as
            // this page, an Ajax proxy would be better
            type: 'jsonp',
            url: 'http://www.sencha.com/forum/remote_topics/index.php',
            reader: {
                root: 'topics',
                totalProperty: 'totalCount'
            },
            // sends single sort as multi parameter
            simpleSortMode: true,
            // sends single group as multi parameter
            simpleGroupMode: true,

            // This particular service cannot sort on more than one field, so grouping === sorting.
            groupParam: 'sort',
            groupDirectionParam: 'dir'
        },
        sorters: [{
            property: 'threadid',
            direction: 'ASC'
        }],
        autoLoad: true,
        listeners: {

            // This particular service cannot sort on more than one field, so if grouped, disable sorting
            groupchange: function(store, groupers) {
                var sortable = !store.isGrouped(),
                    headers = grid.headerCt.getVisibleGridColumns(),
                    i, len = headers.length;

                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    headers[i].sortable = (headers[i].sortable !== undefined) ? headers[i].sortable : sortable;
                }
            },

            // This particular service cannot sort on more than one field, so if grouped, disable sorting
            beforeprefetch: function(store, operation) {
                if (operation.groupers && operation.groupers.length) {
                    delete operation.sorters;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    function renderTopic(value, p, record) {
        return Ext.String.format(
            '<a href="http://sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?t={2}" target="_blank">{0}</a>',
            value,
            record.data.forumtitle,
            record.getId(),
            record.data.forumid
        );
    }

    var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
        clicksToEdit: 1,
        autoCancel: false,
        listeners:{
            edit: function(editor, e){
                Ext.MessageBox.alert(
                    'Just create Ajax recuest here. Post changed record:<br/>' +
                    Ext.JSON.encode(e.record.data)
                );
            }
        }
    });    

    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        width: 700,
        height: 500,
        collapsible: true,
        title: 'ExtJS.com - Browse Forums',
        store: store,
        loadMask: true,
        selModel: {
            pruneRemoved: false
        },
        multiSelect: true,
        viewConfig: {
            trackOver: false
        },
        features:[{
            ftype: 'grouping',
            hideGroupedHeader: false
        }],
        plugins: [rowEditing],
        // grid columns
        columns:[{
            xtype: 'rownumberer',
            width: 50,
            sortable: false
        },{
            tdCls: 'x-grid-cell-topic',
            text: "Topic",
            dataIndex: 'title',
            flex: 1,
            renderer: renderTopic,
            sortable: true,
            editor: {
                allowBlank: false
            }
        },{
            text: "Author",
            dataIndex: 'username',
            width: 100,
            hidden: true,
            sortable: true
        },{
            text: "Replies",
            dataIndex: 'replycount',
            align: 'center',
            width: 70,
            sortable: false,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                allowBlank: false,
                minValue: 1,
                maxValue: 150000
            }
        },{
            id: 'last',
            text: "Last Post",
            dataIndex: 'lastpost',
            width: 130,
            renderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('n/j/Y g:i A'),
            sortable: true,
            groupable: false,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                allowBlank: false,
                format: 'm/d/Y',
                minValue: '01/01/2006',
                minText: 'Cannot have a start date before the company existed!',
                maxValue: Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'm/d/Y')
            }
        }],
        renderTo: Ext.getBody()
    });
});
```

Comment: I have got the editing working but no luck with new record insertion, no matter what method I call (insert/add), it doesn't add to the store.

Comment: Buffered store doesn't support insert operation. Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19913300/820436 When we try insert new record to store we get error: 'Object has no method filterBy'. But You can create pop up ext window with form for insert new record